# Example of CTE to prove it is better than Cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cursor, common-table-expression

I have read that CTE are better than cursor. But I am unable to find the simple clear example which can prove this. I am newbie in Sql Server 2005 and to understand it I need a simple example in which we are storing value via CTE and processing it one by one.

Comment: how about you write and benchmark some?

Comment: 'I need a simple example in which we are storing value via CTE and processing it one by one' - can you process one record at a time using CTEs? I thought they were a way of defining your queries in terms of virtual temporary tables

Comment: @Mitch I'll try to post some query in which you people can help me in converting to CTE. I think thatwill be the good idea for me to learn.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for your respose. As a beginner there are several other related questions are running in my mind.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: a better idea is for you to convert; that way you practice and get better.

Comment: If you're a beginner at SQL, this kind of proof isn't going to teach you anything, the moreso that you're asking others to solve it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Cursor, the sequence of rows are get executed one by one because it fetch only one row at a time. So it takes more time when we use Cursor in tables which has more rows.

Answer (score 0):

CTE yields a faster result in a recursive scenario. The result of CTE is repeatedly used to get the final resultset. So since you have taken your where clause or subquery in CTE, definitely it is going to show performance improvement.  While cursors flow of execution is synchronous(it executes one by one), it is bound to take more time.
Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Just a note, in many scenarios, temp tables gives better performance then CTE also, so you should give a try to temp tables as well.
Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/d040d19d-016e-4a21-bf44-a0359fb3c7fb